# using regex to modify an xml

Tags: regex, editplus

I need to change the following

```
<elor>crap</elor></utha>
```

to

```
    <elor>crap</elor>
</utha>
```

I want to use regex to do this, I don't want any alignment mismatch (for some lame reason)
it would be more helpful if anyone could point out editplus3 regex for this.

Let me broaden the scope of this question, I used java DOM API to add element to existing XML, where this alignment mismatch is happening, I having trouble merging this file. If it is possible to avoid alignment issue at the DOM level I am more than happy to try.

Comment: can't you just open it in notepad and change it there?

Comment: 2345678245 entries, I used java's DOM API to add <elor>crap</elor> to existing XML, but it is pain in the ass to merge it, please help.

Comment: is this being fed to an application?  just about any XML language should read this regardless of the empty space.

Comment: There are really lame reasons, It is breaking our systems (mostly crappy programmers and practices and assumption about XML structure)

Comment: i would use a C# application myself to alter the files. i mean I would create one that would do it..  or you could run it through an XSLT file and it should shape it back up I would think

Comment: I think we don't need tanks to kill a pest right? Thanks though.BTW, I hate XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, just explore EditPlus 3 regex capabilities. use /n and /t judiciously It would solve this issue.